# WooCommerce Filter Orders by Item Count

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Is it possible to create a custom filter in WooCommerce Orders Admin which will allow filtering by the order item count?

We are looking to filter orders with either one item or more than one item (multiple items).

We have the dropdown on the page via the following action and function, but we're stuck on the filter part and how to query each order to find the item count.

```
add_action( 'restrict_manage_posts', 'filter_multi_item_orders', 50 );

function filter_multi_item_orders() {
    global $typenow;
    if ( 'shop_order' != $typenow ) {
        return;
    }?>

    <select name='multi_order_view' id='dropdown_multi_order_view'>
        <option <?php
        if ( isset( $_GET['multi_order_view'] ) && $_GET['multi_order_view'] ) {
            selected( 'all', $_GET['multi_order_view'] );
        }
        ?> value="all"><?php esc_html_e( 'Single and Multi Orders', 'show_multipet_orders' ); ?></option>
        <option <?php
        if ( isset( $_GET['multi_order_view'] ) && $_GET['multi_order_view'] ) {
        selected( 'single', $_GET['multi_order_view'] );
        }
        ?>value="single"><?php esc_html_e( 'Single Orders Only', 'show_multipet_orders' ); ?></option>
        <option <?php
        if ( isset( $_GET['multi_order_view'] ) && $_GET['multi_order_view'] ) {
        selected( 'multi', $_GET['multi_order_view'] );
        }
        ?>value="multi"><?php esc_html_e( 'Multi Orders Only', 'show_multipet_orders' ); ?></option>
    </select>
<?php
}

add_filter( 'request', 'filter_multi_item_orders_query', 100 );
function filter_multi_item_orders_query( $vars ) {
    global $typenow;
    $key = 'post__not_in';
    if ( 'shop_order' == $typenow && isset( $_GET['multi_order_view'] ) ) {
        if ( 'single' == $_GET['multi_order_view'] ) {
            // return orders with $order->get_item_count() == 1
        }
        elseif ( 'multi' == $_GET['multi_order_view'] ) {
            // return orders with $order->get_item_count() > 1
        }
    }
    return $vars;    
}
```

This may not be the best/a possible approach but hope someone can shed some light.

Many thanks

Comment: You would have to join the relevant WooCommerce tables (at least woocommerce_order_items, I think) to the main query here - but WP_Query has no explicit methods to do that AFAIK, so you would have to fiddle the correct values into the correct places yourself - https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/50305/how-to-extend-wp-query-to-include-custom-table-in-query has a pretty extensive explanation, how to start.

Comment: A different approach could be, that you hook into order creation & update, so that you can actually call `get_item_count` there - and store the result into a custom meta field. Then you just have to append the correct meta query, https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#custom-field-post-meta-parameters

Comment: So are you saying the issue is that the actual 'number of items' doesn't exist as a figure in any table? I see the issue then - there's nothing to actually query against. We've got 18k order records so setting that figure in a custom meta field isn't going to be a simple task I don't suspect.

Shame there isn't anything we can write to look at each order on the fly and check 'if get_item_count > 1 show and if not exclude' but that is going to take an age to run and put a load on in terms of processing.

Comment: It is not stored as a number in a single place - it needs to be determined by counting the individual order item records belonging to an order, in the `woocommerce_order_items` table. So the data to query against exists - but it is likely not that trivial to incorporate it into the main query here, using the WP_Query functionality. You’ll have to figure out what kind of JOIN you need to get the necessary info in terms of an SQL query - and then see how you get that JOIN stuffed into the right properties of the query object.

Comment: Understood. Appreciate your insights @04FS

Comment: _“We've got 18k order records so setting that figure in a custom meta field isn't going to be a simple task I don't suspect.”_ - you’d only need to do it once for all 18k orders initially - and I think that could possibly happen “outside” of WP. If you figure out the correct SQL query to determine that number for a product, then you should be able to insert records into the post_meta table based on that accordingly, one for each order id. […]

Comment: […] Hooking into the order creation / update with one or two tiny PHP functions to then set the value for any new, future orders, or ones that get updated by the admin in the backend, would only need to happen as a singular operation for the affected order in each case.

Comment: Well if nothing else hooking into the creation/update action will at least allow for data we can hook into for new orders and can worry about historical orders down the line. Thanks